# Update upsert: date_start field

Tags: php, mongodb

I have 2 date fields: date_start and date_end

```
$criteria = [
    '_id'=>$data->thread,
    'download_id'=>$data->id,
    'ip'=>new MongoInt32(Helper::aton($data->remote_addr)),
];

$status = $nodeThreadsCollection->update($criteria,
    [
        '$set'=>[
            'disconnected'=>(bool)$data->disconnected,
            'date_end'=>new MongoDate(),
        ],
        '$inc'=>[
            'bytes_send'=>new MongoInt64($data->bytes_send),
        ]
    ],[
        'upsert'=>true,
        'w'=>1, 
    ]
);

if(isset($status['updatedExisting']) && !$status['updatedExisting']) {
    $nodeThreadsCollection->update($criteria,
        [
            '$set'=>[
                'date_start'=>new MongoDate(),
            ],
        ],[
            'w'=>0,
        ]
    );
}
```

But it required writeConcern=1  for getting insert status and make secondary query.
How to create it in one query?

Comment: Hmm there is no way to conditionally write the date_start based upon the results of another part of the query within MongoDB itself yet, as such I think two queries is what you have to do, unless of course date_start can be set whenever

Comment: Ah wait you want a $setOnInsert: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/ I believe

Comment: Thank you, and do not expect to see you here ;)

Comment: I haunt this place like a bad rash :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to do this in one go, you can do:

```
<?php
/* Just random test setup */
$m = new MongoClient;
$nodeThreadsCollection = $m->test->test;

$data = new StdClass;
$data->thread = 5;
$data->id = 88;
$data->remote_addr = 76123123;
$data->disconnected = true;
$data->bytes_send = 7234;
*/

$criteria = [
    '_id'=>$data->thread,
    'download_id'=>$data->id,
    'ip'=>new MongoInt32($data->remote_addr),
];

$status = $nodeThreadsCollection->update($criteria,
    [
        '$set'=>[
            'disconnected'=>(bool)$data->disconnected,
            'date_end'=>new MongoDate(),
        ],
        '$setOnInsert'=>[
            'date_start'=>new MongoDate(),
        ],
        '$inc'=>[
            'bytes_send'=>new MongoInt64($data->bytes_send),
        ]
    ],[
        'upsert'=>true,
        'w'=>1,
    ]
);
```

The `$setOnInsert` operator will only set the value if the "upsert" is still just an "insert". Running this script the first time (on a fresh collection) shows:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(5),
    "bytes_send" : NumberLong(7234),
    "date_end" : ISODate("2014-01-10T10:11:16.507Z"),
    "date_start" : ISODate("2014-01-10T10:11:16.507Z"),
    "disconnected" : true,
    "download_id" : NumberLong(88),
    "ip" : 76123123
}
```

And running it for the second time:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(5),
    "bytes_send" : NumberLong(14468),
    "date_end" : ISODate("2014-01-10T10:11:31.184Z"),
    "date_start" : ISODate("2014-01-10T10:11:16.507Z"),
    "disconnected" : true,
    "download_id" : NumberLong(88),
    "ip" : 76123123
}
```

See also: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/